# inputtext only sets value after pressing enter

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Maybe it's a trivial question but I need some understanding here.

I have a `<h:inputText value="#{bean.name}"/>` tag and a "Create" button that inserts the value in the database. If I just type the value and hit "Create", a ConstraintViolationException is thrown because the `#{bean.name}` value is null. I just found out that if I hit enter after typing the value, the string in set in the bound property and the bean is successfully persisted.

So, the question is: wich richfaces or a4j tags I must include around the inputText so that the component sets de bean's value automatically? The code is pretty straightforward:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}">
    <h:commandButton value="Create" actionListener="#{bean.create}"/>
</h:form>
```

**Update:**

I've managed to reach the required behaviour by:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}">
    <a4j:ajax event="keydown" execute="@form"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Is there a tag that I could wrap all the page input components in and remove the `<a4j:ajax>`tag?

Comment: Does this problem also occur if you remove RichFaces entirely from the story (and thus create a completely blank project without RichFaces)? You've in the first snippet by the way a typo in the `value` attribute.

Comment: @BalusC if I remove Richfaces, it works allright. Typo edited.

Comment: OK. What RichFaces version and which JSF impl/version? Your typo is getting worse btw.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information.
`RichFaces Core Implementation by JBoss by Red Hat, version 4.3.0.20121024-M2` and `Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206)`

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce it. When you installed RichFaces, all you did was just dropping the seven required JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib`? Or did you something more?

Comment: It's a Maven Enterprise Project in NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2, RichFaces installed by adding it to the web project's pom.xml. Some more info: the view is based on a template having a "left" and a "center" `<ui:insert>`. In the "left" panel there's a `<ui:include src="menu.xhtml">` tag. Inside of it is a form with a `<h:commandLink action="/edit/main.xhtml">` that navigates to the page in question.

Comment: @BalusC I just figured out the problem. The `menu.xhtml` and the `new.xhtml` (the page with the problem) contained distinct `<h:form>`s each, wrapping the commandLinks and such. I removed every form tag and nested the two `<ui:include>` (left and center) tags in it, removed the `<a4j:ajax>` and now the value is bound to `{#bean.name}`. I think this is not a good practice but it works.

Comment: Okay, you were just nesting forms. This is not caused by RichFaces. You'd still have exactly the same problem when not using RichFaces. While testing it with and without RichFaces, you apparently didn't use the same code.

Comment: Indeed I must have missed something when removing the RichFaces libraries but the forms weren't nested, there were multiple forms in one page (usually an exception is thrown when forms are nested afaik). Would this cause the same problem?

Comment: No, but nested forms would definitely cause exactly this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your knowledge on JSF is remarkable. Would you post the solution so I mark the question "answered"?